# Hide custom object for multiple profiles

Tags: custom-object, security, object

**How to hide custom object for multiple profiles?**

Direct way to do this is go to profile > click edit and un-check object access (read/create/edit/delete/view all/Modify all) and that object won't be visible to that profile.

**How to do same task in mass update for multiple profiles?**

*Context: 
We have more than 130 profiles and have to hide that object for all but one. Org wide default was set as public read/write and now after changing that to private won't do the trick, have to modify check-box in each profile.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps to modify multiples profiles at once.

1. Enable enhanced profile list view. from Setup-> User Interface

[image]

2. Create new List view from profile page.

[image]

3. Select new list view and hover over a permission

[image]

4. Click on Select all the records and save

[image]

Comment: Had to go and select profile for all access fields but modifying initial fields helped to select/deselect all access leveles ( i.e. edit and modify all access) but still this saved lot of time! Thanks